# NInject and NHibernate, sitting in a tree

Tags: nhibernate, ninject

.. but not k.i.s.s.i.n.g

I am trying to use NInject with NHibernate. Through NuGet I am using

- NHibernate           v3.1.0.4000
- NHibernate.Castle    v3.1.0.4000
- NHibernate.Linq      v1.0
- FluentNHibernate     v1.2..0.712
- NInject v2.2.1.4

When I attempt to resolve a class through NInject I get the following error :

Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=2.1.2.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have the following in app.config

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.1.0.4000-2.1.2.4000" newVersion="3.1.0.4000" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

I note that the downloaded NInject package contains the following under \packages\Ninject.2.2.1.4\lib

- ..\net35-Client
- ..\net35-Full
- ..\net40-Client
- ..\net40-Full

When I use NuGet to manage packages for a particular library which of the above versions is being included? Is this a problem that can be resolved by manually adding a reference to the correct Ninject dll?

TIA

Comment: Drop NHibernate.Linq, you're using NH3 which has it's own LINQ provider.

Comment: +1 for using sitting in a tree in the title.

Comment: Thanks Phill. I've removed NH.Linq and replaced my session.Linq call with session.Query in my repository class. However, our repository base extends NHibernateContext. Where is NHibernateContext in NH3 or what has it been superceded with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NuGet decides which version is used depending on the project type. E.g. is you are writing a .NET Client profile assembly then it will add a reference to net40-Client

You can reference any assembly you like manually. But normally NuGet already chooses the correct version.

Answer (score 2):

Dropping the reference to NH.Linq resolved the problem as Phill suggested

Comment: sorry for late response, glad it solved your problem. I'm not sure about NH Context, I haven't had a need to extend on NH3 besides user types.